# Query Mapper Entity by Child Join

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

I have a simple OnetoOne relationship for my Lift app (mapped with  Mapper), my 2 entities.

```
class Game extends KeyedMapper[Long,Game] {
  object week extends MappedInt(this)
... other fields omitted...
}

class Pick extends KeyedMapper[Long,Pick] {
object gameId extends MappedLongForeignKey(this,Game)
def week = gameId.obj.map(_.week.is) openOr 0
... other fields omitted...
}
```

Now I want to query all Picks that have a Game in Week 1.. My attempt

```
 Pick.findAll(By(Pick.week,1))
```

I was hoping this would work (a la JPA/Hibernate)

```
Pick.findAll(By(Pick.gameId.week,1))
```

Of course none of these work, any ideas for a newb?

Comment: I got it working using..

    In(Pick.gameId,Game.id,By(Game.week,week))

But this uses an "IN" statement and not a Join. I guess it will have to do for now

Comment: That's correct, mapper has no support for JOIN in queries.